# Request file checksum from FTP server?

Tags: ftp, checksum

I am downloading some large files from a remote FTP server. Is it possible to request the server to send me checksums (e.g. sha256, or related variants) for the files in question?

Answer (score 3):

**Your remote FTP server must support the checksum calculation**.

Not all FTP servers support this; even the RFC specification does not define a command to calculate a checksum of a remote file. Many modern FTP servers support determining checksums (CRC-32, MD5 or SHA-1) of remote files. And they use different commands like `XSHA1`, `XSHA256`, `XSHA512`, `MD5`, `XMD5`, `XCRC`, and `HASH`

Comment: For those curious, these `X*` and `HASH` commands for FTP are defined in this IETF draft: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-ftpext2-hash-03

Comment: Some examples of servers that DO support it would be useful. Does anyone know any?